# Adobe AIR canvas dimensions messed up

Tags: javascript, air, canvas

I'm messing about with Canvas in Adobe Air. But their seems to be some issue with the mouse coordinates. The more I click towards the right, the difference between the draw position and actual click increases.
My code is

```
Wb.canvas.fillRect(evt.clientX-canvasTag.clientX, evt.clientY-canvasTag.clientY, 50, 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are clicking on canvas then you should just use [`localX`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#localX) and [`localY`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#localY) like this:

```
Wb.canvas.fillRect(evt.localX, evt.localY, 50, 50);
```

Comment: this doesn't work, localX and localY are not even defined in Javascript. And why does the difference keep increasing?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of messing around, it's fixed. canvas width and height should be set as html attributes and not in the stylesheet. Then it works perfectly.

Correct:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Incorrect:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="width:600px;height:400px"></canvas>
```